# Node not able to log my request in terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, terminal

I am relatively new to coding node and keep coming across barriers when trying to learn, I am following a course and when trying to run the attached code snippet I keep receiving error messages.

I have tried to follow all the suggested articles and advice I can find but can't get a result.

Can someone help? [VS code - terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bJry.png)

Comment: post actual code instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You are in node env, you need to exit by press "control + D" and try it again.